# On the the number of intersections of a knotted polygon with a plane.(Milnor's paper)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

I'm trying to understand the article "on the total curvature of knots" by John. W. Milnor. [here is the free access to the article](http://mduchin.math.tufts.edu/UCD/116/milnor.pdf) .

---

the last theorem in this paper indicates that for every knotted polygon in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $\mu < \infty$ there exists a plane that intersects the polygon in at least 6 points. Through the proof of the theorem, the author denotes the polygon by $P$ and then after some steps, he divides the polygon into two polygons $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ such that $P_{1}$ is knotted with fewer sides than $P$ and then proves the theorem. My question is how did the author claim that $P_{1}$ has fewer sides than $P$?

thank you in advance for your helps.

Comment: I have removed the tag (geometry), which is deprecated on MO and should not be used (see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). If there are some other geometry-related tags that would be suitable here, please add them instead. (You have included ([tag:dg.differential-geometry]). I though about adding ([tag:mg.metric-geometry]) and perhaps ([tag:polygons]) - since I was not really sure, leaving the decision to you seemed like a better idea.

Comment: The link to Milnor's paper is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in the paper, but Milnor wrote once $\mu(P)\geqslant 3$ instead of $\mu(P,\mathfrak{b})\geqslant 3$ [page 257, line 9].

Denote by $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n$ the number of edges in $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P$.
Observe that $n_1+n_2=n+4$.
Further, note that $n_1\geqslant5$ and $n_2\geqslant5$ (count number of minima and maxima in $P_1$ and $P_2$).
So
$$n_1=n+4-n_2<n.$$